# showing product short description below the image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that I added to functions.php to show product short description. But I want the description to be shown on top of the price, but it's currently showing  it above the product image. How can I show the product short on top the price?

```
public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_add_short_description' );
/**
 * WooCommerce, Add Short Description to Products on Shop Page
 *
 */
function wc_add_short_description() {
    global $product;

    ?>
        <div itemprop="description">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post-> post_excerpt ) ?>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To display the short description on top of the Price you need to specify a priority to your `add_action` function.

Depending on your configuration, the priority may be different but for me it's `5` to display between title and price

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_add_short_description', 5 );
```